# Android USB Host API - how can I achieve native USB speeds?

Tags: android, usb, tablet

I am trying to use the Android USB Host API in order to achieve native USB speeds (on the order of Mbps). I've seen some examples online that use some constants to set up baud rates of 9600. However, I would like to use bulk transfers and control transfers (as necessary, I'm not really sure about how these work, and which constants to use) in order to achieve native USB speeds. Is there any way to do this, and if so, does anyone have some sample code that they would be willing to share? Thanks!

Note: I've also rooted my Android Nexus 7 tablet just in case. I figured that since apps like StickMount need root access, root might be necessary to achieve native USB speeds.

Comment: It's unlikely that you will be able to achieve the full USB bus bandwidth through the userspace APIs, but what is your goal?  What sort of peripheral are you hoping to talk to?  Without the *precise* details of the types of transactions you hope to perform, your question is near meaningless.  Note that a baud rate (applicable to a USB-serial implementation) is likely an order of magnitude slower than even the slowest effective USB data rate, unless there are architectural flaws in your implementation or protocol (such was waiting across the USB latency for a response).

Comment: For example, one application would be sending data back and forth to an Arduino board, or a Raspberry Pi, or even an FPGA. I would like to be able to achieve USB data transfer, not necessarily through a serial implementation (because as you mentioned, this would be much slower). How can I use the USB Host API to send data over USB at USB data rates instead of serial data rates? Thanks!

Comment: Again, this would depend **almost entirely** on the *specifics* of the device you are connecting.  AFAIK, a raspberry pi doesn't even implement a USB client mode (and while you may be able to hack that on a model A, a model B has a hub in the way).

Comment: Do you know what types of devices would support this type of communication?

Comment: You've failed to specify what you ultimately hope to achieve, hence your question is not answerable in the format of this site.  Edit it and be *specific* about the problem you are trying to solve.